# Yii2, сделать фильтр данных в GridView

Tags: php, yii2

Добрый день! Есть проект на Yii2 что-то типа каталога, вывожу данные о продуктах через GridView, выводится только основная информация при переходе на страницу продукта там уже присутствует подробная информация.

Необходимо сделать фильтр как по соновным полям так и по дополнительным, но чтобы эти дополнительные не присутствовали в таблице GridView, а сам фильтр был.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое реализовать.

Comment: http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-razbiraemsya-s-gridview.html

Comment: Дополнительные данные я так понимаю связаны по связям, тойсть в самой модельке есть связь например один ко многим? Если да то это реализуется в Search модельке где прописана логика фильтрации

Comment: да, вы правы, мне не понятно как вывести сам такой фильтр в GridView, эти дополнительные input-ы и select-ы?

Comment: @Rumato, лезьте непосредственно в GridView ищите где он строит/выводит фильтры. Создавайте свой класс по типу MyGridView в котором переопределите метод который выводит filter row. Вот собственно и все. Подсказка метод renderFilters().

Answer (score 1):

Извините - мало информации.
Опишите подробнее модель,бд и какие таблицы будут использованы.

А вообще подход типовой - его кстати предлагает Gii - вы делаете к модели ее наследованную версию МодельSearch
Gii вам сгенерит модельку в которой прям таки напишет:
/**
 * МодельSearch represents the model behind the search form about `models\Модель`.
 */
class МодельSearch extends Модель

В самой модели поиска вы можете произвольно добавить сколько вам угодно параметров в метод поиска который используется в гриде. Трудно угадать какая у вас бд,но вот к примеру как может это выглядеть (у меня). Не могу утверждать что тут все подходы единственно верные,но смысл и способы использования показывает.

```
public function search($params, $type = 1, $map = null, $paginationOff = null)
    {
        $query = Product::find();

        if (isset($params['type']) && in_array($params['type'], array_flip(Product::getTypes()))) {
            $this->setAttribute('type', $params['type']);
        } else {
            $this->setAttribute('type', $type);
        }

        $this->load($params);
        // array load 
        $type2 = @$params['ProductSearch']['type2'];
        $appPlatforms = @$params['ProductSearch']['appPlatforms'];
        $country = @$params['ProductSearch']['country_id'];
        $apps_count = @$params['ProductSearch']['apps_count'];
        $appCategory = @$params['ProductSearch']['appCategory'];
        $qty_staff = @$params['ProductSearch']['qty_staff'];
        $since_date = @$params['ProductSearch']['since_date'];
        $title = @$params['ProductSearch']['title'];
        $city = @$params['ProductSearch']['city_id'];


        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => self::PAGE_SIZE
            ],
        ]);

        if ($paginationOff) {
            $dataProvider->pagination = false;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'uid' => $this->uid,
            'type' => $this->type,
        ]);

        // Ключевое слово
        if ($title) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Product.title', $title]);
        }
        // Type2 parametr
        if ($type2) {
            if (is_array($type2)) {
                foreach ($type2 as $item) {
                    $query->andFilterWhere(['Product.type2' => $item]);
                }
            }
        }
        // Страна
        if ($city) {
            if (is_array($city)) {
                $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'Product.city_id', $city]);
            }
        }
        if ($country) {
            if (is_array($country)) {
                $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'Product.country_id', $country]);
            }
        }
        // Колличество сотрудников
        if ($qty_staff) {
            if (is_array($qty_staff)) {
                $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'Product.qty_staff', $qty_staff]);
            }
        }
        // Год основания
        if ($since_date) {
            if (is_array($since_date)) {
                $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'Product.since_date', $since_date]);
            }
        }

        // технологии
        if (@$params['ProductSearch']['_tech']) {
            $query->leftJoin('technology', '`technology`.`Product_uid` = `Product`.`uid`');
            $query->andFilterWhere(['`technology`.title' => $this->_tech]);
        }
        // Специализация
        if (@$params['ProductSearch']['_spec']) {
            $query->leftJoin('specialization', '`specialization`.`Product_uid` = `Product`.`uid`');
            $query->andFilterWhere(['`specialization`.title' => $this->_spec]);
        }

        if ($this->type == 1) {
            // приложения
            $query->leftJoin('app_to_dev', '`app_to_dev`.`devId` = `Product`.`uid`');
            $query->leftJoin('application', '`application`.`id` = `app_to_dev`.`appId`');
            $query->leftJoin('app_developer', '`app_developer`.`devId` = `Product`.`uid`');
            $query->leftJoin('application as applicationDev', '`applicationDev`.`developer_native_id` = `app_developer`.`native_id`');
            $query->select(['Product.*, count(`app_developer`.id) + count(`app_to_dev`.id) as count, `application`.`store` as store, `applicationDev`.`store` as store2']);
            $query->groupBy(['`Product`.`uid`']);

            if ($appPlatforms) {
                if (is_array($appPlatforms)) {
                    if (count($appPlatforms) == 1) {
                        foreach ($appPlatforms as $item) {
                            $query->andFilterWhere(['or',
                                ['`application`.`store`' => $item],
                                ['`applicationDev`.`store`' => $item]]);
                        }
                    } elseif (count($appPlatforms) > 1) {
                        $query->andFilterWhere(['or',
                            ['in', '`application`.`store`', $appPlatforms],
                            ['in', '`applicationDev`.`store`', $appPlatforms]]
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```